# HTML5 camera (phonegap) functions

Tags: html, camera

i am very slowly going from html to html5 phonegap, and i am amazed with the possibilities. 
i would like to know how to create a button that when pressed lets create a picture and then sends (automatically) the picture to a fixed email address.

Thanks for any information.

Also if anyone has any good startingpoint for a HTML person to go to HTML5 Phonegapper please let me know.

Comment: Anyone? :) Still something i am interested in :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still searching or for at least people like me, who visit this link searching some HTML5 Camera API, below is the solution I Have.

You can capture picture either from HTML5 input tag with type = "file"

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

You can also achieve by using Phonegap camera api,

see below links

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_camera_camera.md.html
http://ventusmoso.com/phonegap/jquerymobile/phonegap-camera-tutoria/

For emailing captured picture, better use phonegap email plugin

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer